# How to change layout when rotate?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `xml` in `layout-normal`, `layout-large` and `layout-land`. What I'm trying to do is to use the provided `xml` in specific `orientation`.

I already search for it here and this are what I've already tried.

1) I used different `layout` name but same `ids` in it and override `onConfigurationChanged` and set the `layout` there. Here's my code

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login2);
    }
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login );
    }
}
```

It does changed but when the screen rotates the inputed data in the `EditText` is gone. I tried to use `onSaveInstanceState` to save the `instance` but still the same. It looks like it destroys the activity and create a new one where all my widget that is initialized in `onCreate` is gone.

2) Then I found `layout-land` and just put the landscape layout there with same layout name like in `layout-normal` and `layout-large` example is

`res/layout-land -> activity_login.xml`

`res/layout-normal-> activity_login.xml`

`res/layout-large-> activity_login.xml`

and removes the `onConfigurationChanged` on the code but still doesn't work.

In my `AndroidManifest` in `LoginActivity` I put

```
     <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/DefaultTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Is there anyway to change the layout when screen is rotated? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "screen size" qualifier has higher precedence than the "orientation" qualifier. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

> Android supports several configuration qualifiers and you can add multiple qualifiers to one directory name, by separating each qualifier with a dash. Table 2 lists the valid configuration qualifiers, in order of precedence

Suppose you have these files:

```
res/
    layout-normal/
        layout.xml
    layout-land/
        layout.xml
```

If you have a normal screen size device, it won't matter whether you use portrait or landscape. `layout-normal` will always be chosen over `layout-land`.

You can solve this two different ways.

First, you could put your "default" layout in the plain `layout` directory (instead of `layout-normal`). So your files would be

```
res/
    layout/
        layout.xml
    layout-land/
        layout.xml
```

Second, you could combine qualifiers in order to make it obvious that you're differentiating between portrait and landscape. So your files would be

```
res/
    layout-normal/
        layout.xml
    layout-normal-land/
        layout.xml
```

Comment: I think even the Android documentation does not make these details so obvious.  Personally, I never face the OP's problem because my landscape files are placed in the default location +1.

Comment: When I tried it, it only uses the right layout when the app is just started when I rotate it what the app first started to use will be use until I close the app. It will just change when I close the app and open it again in landscape position.

Comment: Do you have `onConfigurationChanged()` in your activity or `android:configChanges` attribute on your activity tag in the manifest?

Comment: @BenP. I already removed the `onConfigurationChanged()` in my activity and yes I have `android:configChanges` in my manifest. Should I remove it as well? It looks like this `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: It's working now :) I removed the `android:configChanges` in my manifest

Comment: As you have figured out, you should remove that attribute. You can think of that attribute as saying "these are the configuration changes that I want to handle myself" and, in general, you don't ever want to handle any of them yourself. This attribute is commonly used to _avoid_ activity destruction/recreation due to things like rotation, but when properly understood and implemented, this destruction/recreation process actually helps you (the developer).

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be missing the point of the `layout-land` folder.  It should be the case that whatever layout you specify there, say `some_activity.xml`, will be automatically used when the device rotates to landscape.  You can name the layout file the same exact name which is already being used by your potrait version.  And the layout file itself can also use the same IDs to name the various widgets which appear.

With regard to you losing some UI state when the device is rotated, you might have to override `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and save some state from your UI when a rotation happens.  This doesn't really have anything to do with which layout file gets shown though.

Comment: Did you use the exact same name?  Is your layout XML for landscape any different than portrait?

Comment: The problem is that the `normal` qualifier has higher precedence than the `land` qualifier. See my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't require to create another `.xml` like `activity_login2`, you can use same `activity_login.xml`.

Android have default folder **/res/layout** which includes all your layout. So whenever you rotate device it will use same **activity_login.xml** file.

you can add a new folder /res/layout-land, copy **activity_login.xml** into it and make the needed adjustments.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login2); // it will use .xml from /res/layout
    }
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login); // it will use xml from /res/layout-land
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a `layout` folder where can I set the landscape layout for bigger screens?

Comment: should I delete the `xml` in `res/layout-normal` and `res/layout-large` ?

Comment: @mori : you can try both. Take one which is suitable for you.