# Android Layout and Filling in Available Space

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I have an activity in which I've got two layouts that should mirror one another, with elements taking up available space, but also being pulled to the left and right - so that they sit to the left and right side of the screen when rotated.

I've managed to get the left side to do exactly what it should do, but I cannot for the life of me work out what's missing on the right hand side to make it behave in a mirrored manner.

The main layout uses a Horizontal Linear Layout (Blue outline) to hold two vertical LinearLayouts (green outlines), which each hold three HUDs (also an xml layout) one highlighted in red on each side. What I am trying to do is firstly, have the imageviews aligned to the right, and then the progressbars fill the remaining space as they do on the left hand side.

Additionally, when the phone is rotated (either direction) I can only see the left hand HUDs - I assume that the others are hidden behind the surfaceview in the middle. I'd like the right hand characters to drop into the space on the right of the screen (second image).

The main activity has the two LinearLayouts in it, but the left and right HUD elements are added programatically when the player party is loaded up - not sure if that's playing a part in why the expected behaviour isn't working.

[image]

[image]

I have changed the following line in the right HUD xml:
android:layout_width="wrap_content" from "match_parent" as when it had that, the progress bars filled the entire space and pushed the character icons off the side of the screen. (The individual layout view in Android Studio looked fine though)

Here's the layout code:
Main Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/worldScreen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"

tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llButtons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    ... Top part works fine. lot of code cluttering the question
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llCharHUDs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/llButtons">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llCharHUDsLeft"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llCharHUDsRight"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_realm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/worldSurface"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/worldSurface"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/actionImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/actionButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/actionButton"
    app:srcCompat="?android:attr/panelBackground" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/actionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="actionButton"
    android:text="Button"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/worldSurface" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

char_hud_left (The one displaying as I want it to)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:gravity="left">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCharPortrait"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/empty_face" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCharName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbBarHealth"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbBarAction"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbBarMana"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llEffects"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>




    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

And the char_hud_right which is the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" <== Changed this from "match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCharName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pbBarHealth"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:rotation="-180"
                android:progress="0"
                android:progressTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pbBarAction"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:rotation="-180"
                android:progress="0"
                android:progressTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pbBarMana"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:rotation="-180"
                android:progress="0"
                android:progressTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llEffects"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivCharPortrait"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/empty_face"
            />


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Edit:
As described below in a comment, if I adjust the HUD_right xml and simply move the Imageview Above the LinearLayout, I almost get what I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivCharPortrait"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/empty_face"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCharName"
            ... Remainder of this code removed for clarity

        </LinearLayout>




    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

And when rotated, it again almost does what I want, though I'm not certain that it is not going to the middle of the screen below the surfaceview:

[image]

Is this the sort of scenario where I should check all my distances and manually set distances in pixels on a rotation? I was hoping to have the XML look after it for me, but can go down the other route if it is better?

Edit 2:
Following this question ([How to change layout when rotate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45687034/how-to-change-layout-when-rotate)) I've also achieved a better outcome when the screen is rotated, but only when the icons are on the left hand of the progress bars, not the right hand side.

Edit 3:
As mentioned in the comments below, I've managed to get what I want in what I assume is not the most elegant way at all, but I added another LinearLayout to hold just the image and the other linearlaout, then added a weight to it to finally get the progress bars to expand out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="end">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCharName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/pbBarHealth"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="4dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:progress="0"
                    android:progressTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:rotation="-180" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/pbBarAction"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="4dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:progress="0"
                    android:progressTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                    android:rotation="-180" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/pbBarMana"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="4dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:progress="0"
                    android:progressTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                    android:rotation="-180" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llEffects"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivCharPortrait"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/empty_face" />


    </LinearLayout>




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to achieve something similar to the image below.

To achieve this, whenever you're adding the `char_hud_right.xml` programmatically, make sure to add width and height as a **wrap_content** and `layout_gravity` as **end**.

The layout in the image below is created statically. I've kept everything as it is and have only changed the properties of the included layout. If you're adding this layout dynamically, make sure you'll set the right height, width and layout gravity.

```
      <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llCharHUDsRight"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp">

            <include
                layout="@layout/char_hud_right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Hiya, thanks for taking the time to answer, I'll try on the basis of what you've written, but I certainly don't want the size to be wrap_content. I want it to fill in the available space like the left ones do. There's the icon, then the LinearLayout fills the rest of the available space with the progress bars. I'm hoping for that same effect on the right hand side, just with the image on the right. If I put the image left, it works how I want it in terms of scaling and so on, I just want the image on the right hand side? I'm clearly missing something silly. I'll edit to show what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, these are added statically, just the contents filled dynamically, so I steered you down the wrong road there.

Comment: I've added it statically to demonstrate it. I assume that you already have implemented the mechanism to add it dynamically. let's keep it as it is and make changes in the char_hud layout directly. Considering what you said earlier, I'll suggest changing the width of both the char_hud layouts to match_parent. Also, on top level LinearLayout add `android:gravity="start"` for char_hud_left.xml and `android:gravity="end"` for char_hud_right.xml. Apart from this, I noticed that the LinearLayout which holds progressbar and textview, needs to use the width as match_parent.

Comment: I don't think I've done it in the most elegant way, but this solution helped me get it in the end, so I'll accept and post an final edit in my question with the output. The final bit that foxed it was adding a weight to one of the LinearLayouts so that it filled the remaining space. `android:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: I'm glad that it worked for you somehow.